# JQuery ajax return Conten-disposition null, but header is there

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I need to catch "Content-Disposition" header on https response .. about a file download, but it fails. I'm using Spring (Security) REST with HTTPS. My frontend is made with JQuery. I appreciate any help. I'm working by 2 days and .. nothing!

Important: when i observe on browser network console .. the headers on https datagram is ok. Content-Disposition is there. And the file (a image) already arrived from backend. a image was attached ...

```
        $.ajax({
            url: backend+"/noauthe/filemngr/Download",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            headers: { 'Content-Type':'image/jpeg' },
            responseType:'arraybuffer',
            data: JSON.stringify(fileDescriptor)
        }).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var downloadBlob = document.createElement("a");
            downloadBlob.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type: jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")}));
            downloadBlob.download = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition").split("=")[1].trim();
            document.body.appendChild(downloadBlob);
            downloadBlob.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadBlob);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('[ERROR]');
            console.log(jqXHR);
        });
```

[here is a image to my browser debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64cV4.jpg)

help?

Comment: Have you debugged from developer console to see what is going on?

Comment: yes! and nothing ... i'm using XMLHttpRequest. it's ok now ... thanks